# Remove the Week Number for sap.ui.unified.Calendar

Tags: sapui5

The sap.ui.unified.Calendar has a week number next to the first day of the week (sunday), this month shows how it may confuse users.

[image]

There doesnt seem to be an easy way to configure its visibility.

I can hide it with a hack, but leaves a gap

```
.sapUiCalWeekNum {
   color: #fff !important;
}
```

Anybody have a better way of hiding the week number? (other than islamic calendar)

Answer (score 2):

[As of UI5 version 1.48](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/332cf978fa4b18970f6a35d856ae8a81f635c01f), there is a property [**`showWeekNumbers`**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar/methods/setShowWeekNumbers) which is enabled by default. When disabled, the week numbers are gone:

[image: SAPUI5 sap.ui.unified.Calendar without week numbers]

---

#### UI5 version 1.48 and earlier

<sup>This approach is no longer recommended since UI5 version 1.48. See the updated answer above.</sup>

Try

```css
.sapUiCalWeekNum { display : none }
.sapUiCalMonthView .sapUiCalFirstWDay { margin-left : 6.75% }
```

The first selector removes the week days -- leaving the space indeed since it's a span, not a div :-(
The second selector evens the space between left margin and right margin (the standard left-margin is `12.5%` so this makes it even).

Comment: Cheers the second line looks right, doesnt work for me unless overide with !important, trying to avoid overides